# tcp retransmission on lan, wifi is fine

Tags: lan, nas, wireshark, tcpip, synology

I have a Dell XPS 17 laptop (about 5 years old) running Windows 7 and a Synology RS412 NAS. I also have various other networked devices (servers, routers, laptops, pcs). Some are in my domain, some are not. All these other devices have no issues connecting to and using the Synology NAS. The Dell has no issue connecting to the NAS... using the Wifi connection. It has no issues connecting to other local or internet devices (the wireless on the router is on a schedule and only on in the evenings).

Using the cable however has ... issues. Pinging the NAS works. Telnet  5000 and typing gibberish returns a 302 and a disconnect. Connecting to the NAS's web interface using a browser (any browser) or a fileshare using Windows Explorer results in the program hanging with no timeout.

Wireshark gives me TCP Retransmission, TCP ACK DUP and TCP Previous Segment not captured errors.

This in itself caused me to try the Wifi and conclude that this indeed worked.

I have used several (otherwise tested to be working) UTP cables to exclude a faulty cable. For a physical failure it seems oddly specific as well... though you never know...

**The question:**

So, barring a physical failure of the NIC, is there any setting in Windows that can cause this behavior?

Comment: You can always use a Linux live-CD to exclude any Windows issue.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed it by lowering the MTU until it worked and disabling Jumbo Frames.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds much, much more likely to be a NIC/cable/switch-port fault than anything OS-level.  While TCP retransmits can be caused by software (such as the OS network stack) sending out malformed packets, on switched networks, this is almost always a result of something wrong with the hardware or physical environment.  (I am making the assume your LAN is using a switch, not a hub, as packet collisions in a hub's collision domain will create retransmits as well.)

As suggested, you can try running a different OS (such as a Linux liveCD) to eliminate the application software and network stack from the equation, but more than 99 times out of 100, this is a result of something wrong in layer 1 of the [OSI network model](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/OSI_Layers.asp) (and sometimes layer 2 or 3).

As such, the best, quickest options are usually to clean out the Ethernet ports (blowing them out with canned air)), trying a new cable, checking for sources of interference (is your network cable maybe running right next to a big power supply, for example), changing the ports the cable is connected to and then upgrading your network-related firmware and drivers (if applicable).

If that doesn't work, it's a matter of isolating which device is failing (port on the computer, port on the NAS, switch) and procuring replacement hardware, sad to say.